# c# клиент для asterisk

Tags: c#, debian, asterisk, opensource, sip

Всем привет. Хочу написать софтфон для asterisk. 
Пробовал библиотеку asterNET, но не понял, почему для меня она не работает. 
[мой вопрос на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738430/c-sharp-asttray-timeout-waiting-for-protocol-identifier?noredirect=1#comment82437046_47738430)

проект asttray - то что я пытался использовать для изучения, ошибку выдавал следующую.

[image: asttray c# - разработка29.рф]

по каким то причинам он менял значения переменных, и эти дейстия не отлавливались, когда я производил отладку.

есть ли русскоязычный мануал? или opensource проекты, более доступные в понимании?

Comment: К сожалению, поиск библиотек без четких критериев ("более доступные в понимании") - оффтопик. Если вам нужна помощь с конкретной библиотекой - приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы, который каждый сможет скопировать и запустить, и не сводите вопрос к "какую еще библиотеку попробовать".

Comment: @pashapash, вы взяли лишь 7 последних слов из моего вопроса. я в большей степени просил  русскоязычный мануал по asternet. а описание моей проблемы есть в вопросе по ссылке  "мой вопрос на stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Поиск литературы и мануалов - оффтопик на SO (и на русском, и на английском). Вопрос не должен сводиться к "дайте ссылку на мануал". Английский Stack Overflow - отдельный сайт. Если у вас есть конкретная проблема с с asternet, и вы хотите получить решение на русском языке - оформите отдельный вопрос, со всеми деталями, и не сводите его к "дайте мануал на русском".

Comment: @pashapash у меня так много свобоного времени

Comment: у остальных участников его тоже полно

Comment: @pashapash я опечатался, я хотел написать "у меня не так много свободного времени"

Comment: не стоит ценить свое время дороже, чем время других участников. если вам жалко своего времени на оформление вопроса по вашей же проблеме - не удивляйтесь, что другим жалко времени на его решение.

Comment: @pashapash меня удивляет другое

Answer (score 1):

Привет! Вот пара opensource проектов (правда на C++): [MicroSIP](https://www.microsip.org/source) и [tSIP](http://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/index.php?lang=en)